Format Hard Drives using elevated permissions on a Remote PC
I created a C# desktop app that successfully format/rename/clear hard drives using admin permissions( not recommended but only option)
The problem is when I remote into a PC and run the APP, I get access denied error. If I remote in a PC, I can run elevated CMD and format the drive. If a non admin user log into a PC physically and run the App, it works as expected.
I think the issue is with authentication while remote.
Here is a code snipped:
var domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"];
var adminUserText = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminUser"];
var adminPasswordText = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminPassword"];

var password = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in adminPasswordText)
 {
  password.AppendChar(c);
 }

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
 FileName = "cmd.exe",
 Arguments = command,
 UseShellExecute = false,       // Required to use 'runas' for elevated privileges
 Verb = "runas",
 Domain = domain,
 UserName = adminUserText,
 Password = password,
 RedirectStandardError = true,
 RedirectStandardOutput = true,
 CreateNoWindow = true
};

try
{
 using (Process process = Process.Start(startInfo))
  {
     // Process output handling
     string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
     string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

     process.WaitForExit();

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
     {
        
     }
     else
     {
    
     }
  }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {

 }


Why don't you just use PSRemoting with Powershell, then you can do a remote Invoke-Command passing a script with Format-Volume.
